# How to do page transition in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, transition, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to do page transitions whenever the page is routed to a new path. 
I could find awesome transitions @ [AngularJS Transitions by Minko Gechev](http://angular-transitions.mgechev.com/)

But I am not able to apply these transitions on my pages. I am using AngularJS version 1.2.21 which is the latest one. I am also using the latest version of Angular UI Bootstrap as well.

Please advice how to implement page transitions using AngularJS.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the core angular ngAnimate module? It provides hooks for view enter and leave events as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

Comment: One more [project](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1) on the subject. In short, you should set a CSS class to ngView element.

Comment: Thank you guys. The project I shared uses CSS, that is why I was more keen on it. But anyways, since, its not working I will look at the ones shared by you guys. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include ngAnimate module. Do this and everything will be fine :)